# Use Table tag in Android Email

Tags: html, android, email, android-intent

I want my app to construct some HTML and pass it over to an email so my user can send it to whomever they want. I found code on the web that shows how to pass the html via an Intent, but it appears that Html.fromHtml(String source) doesn't understand table tags. Is there anyway I can format an email with table tags? I want to send it through the user's preferred client instead of sending it myself with javamail.

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't handle table tags?  Example?

Comment: @Mayra i can confirm it, Table tags are ignore by the evil Html.fromHtml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `<table>` tag isn't supported.  Supported tags are actually more dependent on the email client you use to send the email - some of them are more finicky/restrictive than others.  Most of them use the super-basic formatting tags like `<b>`, `<i>`, `<h1>`, and so on, though.  The more layout-oriented tags are a lot more spotty, and some (like `<table>`) aren't supported at all.