# android - How to create table in the email body

Tags: android, html

i want to create tables in the email body. I read some where android doesn't support the table tag. How to implement this. please can anybody help me.

**Output:**

[image]

thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the HTML table tag?

Comment: Yes you read it correctly. HTML table tags are not yet supported. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350072/use-table-tag-in-android-email

Comment: you can try using html's div tag..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using HTML's div tag.

Examples :

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47934/DIV-TABLE
2. http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di