# Use of <table> tag in html email in android

Tags: android, html, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android - How to create table in the email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051125/android-how-to-create-table-in-the-email-body)

I want to send an html email from my android application.I am using  tag in this html. I know that Html.fromHtml() method does not support  tags.So the mail shows as plain text.I want to send this data as a table and never attached.How can i achieve this.
I am using

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 emailIntent.setType("text/html");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(emailContent));
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send mail..."));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you are trying to send the data as HTML format??

Comment: Yes.I want to do it with html.

Comment: I could not find a correct answer.I want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this:

```
String body = new String("<html><body><table><tr><td><br/>" +header+"</td></tr><br/><br/>"+"Get <b> Best Score </b> in your Android Phone.<br/>"+"<a href=\"" + link_val + "\">" + text_value+ "</a>");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, html.fromHtml(body));
```

Comment: If, it was not working for you, please post your code..

Comment: Yes.But html.fromHtml(body) did not support <table> tags.

Comment: I am edited my question by adding some code.Please check it.