# Mail html table

Tags: android, email

I am developing an application to send an email with HTML data as the email subject. The HTML contains a table tag in it. But when I get the mail it doesn't look like a table. what is the problem here? the code I used is

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Medicine Details");

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    Html.fromHtml(htmldata));

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email to Friend"));
```

Comment: HTML's table tag is not supported yet for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051125/android-how-to-create-table-in-the-email-body

Comment: then how can i send table as email

Comment: Make use of div.. Refer the answer i have posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051125/android-how-to-create-table-in-the-email-body

Answer (score 1):

A longshot maybe but you can make use of serverbased mail. Your app allready makes use of the internet i guess so you can POST your data to a PHP file that sends the mail in full HTML in all it's glory for you ;)

Comment: +1 I had the same issue once. Having a server backend helps in the case. Then the developer don't have to worry about different mail clients installed on the device and their behaviour. (My issue was I didn't had a server backend, and client didn't want to pay for one either) Also, in the question, if you prefer Intent approach make sure the type is set to `message/rfc822` instead of `text/plain` to avoid showing non-email apps in the chooser on some devices.

Comment: how can i convert my html file into php. I dont have knowledge in php

Comment: If you can create apps for Android you sure can work your way with PHP. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php for all the info on sending mail with PHP.